# Openstack can't find logs from services (nova, neutron etc.)

Tags: logging, ubuntu-18.04, openstack, ubuntu-20.04, openstack-nova

I have installed Openstack Ussuri and Wallaby (two different VMs) using devstack on Ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04 machines (more than one). I'm capable of spawning instances (using `openstack server create`) and all is good. However, I wish to see the logs of the system, which suppose to be at `/var/logs/<service_name>` (according to [this official doc](https://docs.openstack.org/operations-guide/ops-logging.html)). However, I have no such directories at all, even after getting an error on instance spawning.

I have checked, and at the `nova.conf` I have: `debug = True`, I do get the logs from the RabbitMQ, OpenVSwitch and so on, but not from any of the openstack services.

I even searched my entire filesystem for a file that contains `nova` and `log` and there is nothing.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/systemd.html#querying-logs).

Comment: Is there a way to read these as files (for example. if I want to read these into a script)?

Comment: journalctl allows you to write them to a file, e.g. `journalctl -u devstack@* > /tmp/openstack.log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still configure the services to log to a file, but keep in mind that you need to rotate the logs otherwise they will eventually fill up the disk.

To enable logs just add `log_file` under the `[DEFAULT]` section of the service configuration (e.g. `/etc/nova/nova.conf`).

```
[DEFAULT]
log_file = /opt/stack/logs/nova.log
```

The configuration options are documented [here](https://docs.openstack.org/mitaka/config-reference/compute/config-options.html#nova-logging).

You could also just read logs directly from journal, there are a bunch of libraries to assist with this. A better alternative is probably to have journald forward the logs to another service (e.g. rsyslog, splunk) and use those for your post processing.